# Trying to make javascript apply to more than one image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get this script to work on more than one image on a page what do I have to do to change it to have it apply to more than "mapImg"  and "img01". I am assuming that those are the areas of the script that need to be modified ... But this is the first js that I have worked with ...

You can see a sample [here](http://macreviewzone-archive.net/project/template_testpop.html). I want the other images on this page to have the same behavior of the first image when clicked (pretend that they are all different images).

**JavaScript:**

```
// Get the modal

    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption

    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    img.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal

    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal

    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="images/dt_sm.png" alt="Skateboarding in Portland Skidmore Old Town" >

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">`

    <!-- The Close Button -->
    <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

    <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

    <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
    <div id="caption"></div>

</div>
```

**More Details**

Hi, Thanks for your responses. I can see that part of my question above was cut off and one of the labels I used was inaccurate. I have to emphasize that this is the first Javascript that I have tried to modify in my life and though I appreciate the jQuery suggestion, I would like to get my knowledge of the script I am working with at the moment under my belt before I move on to other ways of dealing with the problem. It looks to me like this script is set up to deal with only with one image css styling (myImg) and I want three or four (myImag, hisImag, theirImag etc) The script is also set for one image variable  img01 and i want to effect 4 or 5 images on the page (img01, img02, img03 etc),  with the same modal styling and actions. So instead of copying the script 4 or 5 times and changing the variables, (and I am not sure if you can do that on a single page?), I want to have This particular script apply to more than one set of variables at the moment it seems hardwired for only one?  I know these probably seem like baby step questions ... But I am afraid that is where I am at with Javascript at the moment so if you respond remember that I only know a few sentences in the language you are speaking  ... After next quarter I will understand this stuff much better .... Thanks for your help

Comment: the `id` should be **unique**

Comment: Your question isn't very clear...are you trying to run the same javascript on multiple modals, or a slightly modified version on different modals?

Comment: try using `class` in place of `id` for images

Comment: I think in this case is better use FanyBox or Lightbox. In your example you don't have put img inside the `.modal-content`

Comment: This was the right solution ... Used Lightbox after some investigation ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Using jQuery you can achieve the toggling of images .**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#close01").click(function(){
                $("#img01").toggle();
            });

            $("#close02").click(function(){
                $("#img02").toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
         <span id="close01" >&times;</span>
         <img class="modal-content" id="img01" src="img01.png">
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
         <span id="close02" >&times;</span>
         <img class="modal-content" id="img02" src="img02.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your responses. I can see that part of my question above was cut off and one of the labels I used was inaccurate. I have to emphasize that this is the first Javascript that I have tried to modify in my life and though I appreciate the jQuery suggestion. I would like to get my knowledge of the script I am working with at the moment under my belt before I move on to other ways of dealing with the problem.